# How do i get the cell value by reading a .csv file using php?

Tags: php

I have a .csv file of data.csv and its content shown below

```
ID,Username,   Email,       DateJoined, Password, UserScore, profilePics
1 , Mr. A  , abc@gmail.com, 30-01-2018,  abcd   ,   20     ,    d
2 , Mr. B  , vcs@gmail.com, 31-01-2018,  kjhg   ,   500    ,    a
3 , Mr. B  , a1d@gmail.com, 31-01-2018,  qwwq   ,   233    ,    b
4 , Mr. B  , a3d@gmail.com, 31-01-2018,  asdd   ,   800    ,    y
```

I want to read a cell value of (3,5) in php which means 3rd row and fifth column of the data.csv file so output will be "kjhg" in this case, so proceeding in this way how do i do to read for other cell value. Any comments is valuable to me. Thanking you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by searching through internet

```
<?php

$row = 1;
$mycsvfile = array(); //define the main array.
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $num = count($data);
      $row++;
      $mycsvfile[] = $data; //add the row to the main array.
}
fclose($handle);
}

echo $mycsvfile[3][5]; //prints the 4th row, second column.

?>
```